# Unable to fetch form data in login url

Tags: request, postman, scrapy

I a trying to get some data from hooq.tv website, I found "https://www.hooq.tv/search?page=1&size=24&scope=min%2Cimages&as=TVSHOW" api which gives required data but when I request this api in Postman it does not response json, because it required login detail (email id), then I logged out from hooq.tv and logged in again to get formdata in network tab but I am unable to do so.

"https://www.hooq.tv/in/login-email" this is the login url

Please help

Answer (score 0):

In Postman there is special window for authorization.
[image: Postman authorization]

But are you sure that you are using Rest-api not just the url?

Comment: I didn't get form data from api only. If I can get the login form detail in network tab then I will be able to fill it in postman